# In PIC24 programming, why does AD1PCFGL = 0xFFDF mean assigning analog to AN5?

Tags: pic, adc

I know 0xffdf is a hexadecimal number, but why does the instruction `AD1PCFGL = 0xFFDF;` mean assigning analog to AN5? What has 0xFFDF to do with 5? How are they related?

Comment: The answer to your question most definitely lies in the datasheet.. :-)

Comment: Although... 0xFFDF = 1111111111011111 in binary. As you can see, the 5th bit is different (zero) from the others.

Comment: Thank you! I was originally thinking in this way but I forgot the bit zero...

Answer (score 4):

```
<rant>
```

I cannot emphasis this point enough. **Read the data sheet.** If you don't understand, read it again. Think about what the instruction is actually *doing*. You will never have success working with microcontrollers if you don't understand what the SFRs control.

```
</rant>
```

AD1PCFGL is a 16-bit register according to the [A/D converter datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39705b.pdf). You can't fit 32 bits into a 16-bit space, so ignore the upper byte and focus on the lower one. (Your compiler / assembler is doing this for you, BTW)

[image]

0xDF = 1101 1111, so PCFG5 is being set to 0. Per the description, that makes it an analog-mode pin. I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the relationship between PCFG5 and AN5.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sometimes I am not sure how to interpret the datasheet, but your explanation is quite helpful, thanks!